# How to separate a sentence to a list?

Tags: python-3.x, list, numpy

For example here is my document:

```
docs = '''
The goal of /r/Games is to provide a place for informative and interesting 
gaming content and discussions. Submissions should be for the purpose of 
informing or initiating a discussion, not just with the goal of entertaining 
viewers.
IRC channel: #Games on irc.snoonet.org
For an in-depth explanation of our rules don't forget to check our rules 
wiki page and FAQ!


I've been spending quite a while reading reviews of various players on the 
game. And, it seems (for the most part) it's being received fairly 
positively with gamers. I'm interested to hear how Reddit is enjoy the game 
thus far. Feel free to be as brief, or as thorough as you want.  

Thanks in advance for all replies. '''
```

And I want to separate docs to a list like this:

```
sentence = [[The goal of /r/Games is to provide a place for informative and 
interesting gaming content and discussions. Submissions should be for the 
purpose of informing or initiating a discussion, not just with the goal of 
entertaining viewers. IRC channel: #Games on irc.snoonet.org For an in-depth 
explanation of our rules don't forget to check our rules wiki page and 
FAQ!]], 
[I've been spending quite a while reading reviews of various players on the 
game. And, it seems (for the most part) it's being received fairly 
positively with gamers. I'm interested to hear how Reddit is enjoy the game 
thus far. Feel free to be as brief, or as thorough as you want.], [Thanks in 
advance for all replies.]]
```

And I use `docs.split(' ')` I only can get a dictionary which is like just separate by words

How do I get `sentence`?

Comment: Split by `.` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Look like you could just split it by double new lines `\n\n`

```
docs = '''
The goal of /r/Games is to provide a place for informative and interesting 
gaming content and discussions. Submissions should be for the purpose of 
informing or initiating a discussion, not just with the goal of entertaining 
viewers.
IRC channel: #Games on irc.snoonet.org
For an in-depth explanation of our rules don't forget to check our rules 
wiki page and FAQ!


I've been spending quite a while reading reviews of various players on the 
game. And, it seems (for the most part) it's being received fairly 
positively with gamers. I'm interested to hear how Reddit is enjoy the game 
thus far. Feel free to be as brief, or as thorough as you want.  

Thanks in advance for all replies. '''

sentence = [i.strip() for i in docs.split('\n\n')]
for i in sentence:
    print('i: ' + i + '\n')
```

Output:

```
i: The goal of /r/Games is to provide a place for informative and interesting 
gaming content and discussions. Submissions should be for the purpose of 
informing or initiating a discussion, not just with the goal of entertaining 
viewers.
IRC channel: #Games on irc.snoonet.org
For an in-depth explanation of our rules don't forget to check our rules 
wiki page and FAQ!

i: I've been spending quite a while reading reviews of various players on the 
game. And, it seems (for the most part) it's being received fairly 
positively with gamers. I'm interested to hear how Reddit is enjoy the game 
thus far. Feel free to be as brief, or as thorough as you want.

i: Thanks in advance for all replies.
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to split paragraphs, not sentences. In this case use `.split('\n\n')` or, more generally, use `re.split(r'\n{2,}', docs)`, this will split on 2 or more `'\n'`